# load slick with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

My problem is simple, but I'm missing the forest through the trees...

My page has many slick-sliders. That works well.
These sliders aren't visible in any case. Via onclick-function there will be shown a new div-tag with slick included. (toggle)

The problem is is now:
Slick loads, when page-loading has finished. But only the visible divs.
So, when I toggle a div to get visible, and there's slick in included, Slick is not loaded for this div. I can klick forward or backward of slick-slider and it loads all pictures. But I'd like to load these directly with the onclick-function of the toggle. That would be nice.

And I'm not really good in JS :D

That's where Slick get loaded:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lazy').slick({
       slidesToShow: 6,
      slidesToScroll: 6,
      responsive: [
        {
        breakpoint: 1199,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 5,
            slidesToScroll: 5,
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 991,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 730,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },
      ]
    });
});
```

And here's my toggle:

```
function fotoalbum(id){
       var e = document.getElementById(id);   

       if (e.className == "row fotos-container-deaktiv") {
       e.className = "row fotos-container-produktion";
     } else {
       e.className = "row fotos-container-deaktiv";
     }
  };
```

And now I want, that slick starts, when the function fotoalbum is used.

Can someone help me please. :(
And I'm so sry for my bad english. I hope you can understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".somediv").click(function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('class1');
});

$("#change").click(function(e) {
  $(this).hasClass("change1") ?
    $(this).removeClass('change1').addClass('change2') :
    $(this).removeClass('change2').addClass('change1');
});
```

```css
.somediv {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.class1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.change1 {
  color: blue;
}
.change2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1 somediv">some text</div>


<div class="change1 somediv" id='change'>some other text</div>
```

I would like to encourage you to read about [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

And when you already read this, have look also at [.switchClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/547://) by the author you can refresh slick whenever you add a new div that contain a slick object. You have to add something like `$('.my-slider')[0].slick.refresh()` inside your function.

Cheers